# delimiting ndarray into different columns

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, csv

I have a dataset, where there is a series in the 1st column and a ndarray in the 2nd.
The ndarray is constituted of "," separated values.
How can I split the values into different columns?

```
data sample:


             id                               values
    0      390725715                 (service-selection-page, 1, 3)
    1      682669054                 (mobile-apps full-page, 1, 12)
    2      770810604                (service-selection-page, 2, 41)
    3     1009039867                (list-property full-page, 1, 7)
    4     1523526830                 (service-selection-page, 2, 1)
    5     1495892895                 (mobile-apps full-page, 1, 24)
    6      975125144                (service-selection-page, 1, 37)
```

here, id is a series and values is ndarray.

```
Expected output:
          id                     values             0     1
0      390725715         service-selection-page     1     3
1      682669054         mobile-apps full-page      1     12
2      770810604         service-selection-page     2     41
3     1009039867         list-property full-page    1     7
4     1523526830         service-selection-page     2     1
5     1495892895         mobile-apps full-page      1     24
6      975125144         service-selection-page     1     37
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`df['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))` is what you'd want to do.

For example, if your `df` was like

```
In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame([[390 , pd.np.array(('service-selection-page', 1, 3))],
                            [110 , pd.np.array(('page', 1, 3))]],
                           columns=['id', 'values'])
In [39]: df
Out[39]:
    id                          values
0  390  [service-selection-page, 1, 3]
1  110                    [page, 1, 3]
```

Where, `values` contain numpy arrays, `apply`, `lambda x: pd.Series(x)` on `df['values']`

```
In [40]: df['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
Out[40]:
                        0  1  2
0  service-selection-page  1  3
1                    page  1  3
```

And, you could use join to extend the columns.

```
In [41]: df.join(df['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)))
Out[41]:
    id                          values                       0  1  2
0  390  [service-selection-page, 1, 3]  service-selection-page  1  3
1  110                    [page, 1, 3]                    page  1  3
```